# R - trying to Group a data frame by a factor but capture the count of occurrences of that factor

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I've been working on this data manipulation for over a day and know it should be straightforward...

I have a data frame with 4+ variables. there is a 1:many relationship between reportID and TestResult and a 1:1 relationship between ReportID and all other variables. I think it makes sense to re-cast reportID as a factor but not sure.

```
reportID <- c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1002) 
TestResult <-c("aa","bb","cc","dd","aa","ee")
dateSent <- c(as.Date("2017-08-01"),as.Date("2017-08-01"),as.Date("2017-08-01"),as.Date("2017-08-04"),as.Date("2017-08-05"),as.Date("2017-08-05"))
otherVar1<- c(11,11,11,12,13,13)
df<- data.frame(reportID,TestResult,dateSent,otherVar1)
```

I think dplyr is the right tool here...

what I want is a dataframe like this:

```
reportID Results dateSent       otherVar1
1000     3       2017-08-01         11
1001     1       2017-08-04         12
1002     2       2017-08-05         13
```

Specifically, a row for every result is too much information - I want to count the number of times a result is recorded for each reportID and collect the other information in the data frame.

**Edit/additional note**
In the example data I should have represented the fact that some of the data frame elements had a space in the name. In my real world problem my data looks like this:
    'report ID' <- c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1001, 1002, 1002)

The space in the name of the column created a problem difficult to debug. I ended up using the answer suggested below but used ***slanted*** single quotes.

```
Plot1Data <- VariantReport %>% 
group_by(`report id`,`date sent`,`other variable1`) %>% 
summarise(numresults=n())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not 100% sure i interpreted your requirements correctly, but i think this would work

`df %>% group_by(reportID,dateSent,otherVar1) %>% summarise(numresults=n())`

Comment: I think this is it! Can I put any number of variables in the group_by function if they are uniform within the same report id?

Comment: if all the other variables are 1:1 with the main variable you are looking to understand, then that should be acceptable. if you have any that are 1:many, though, it will not produce the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Sir, If you have more than one `otherVar`, then you might be happy to use `group_by_at`, and specify all `otherVars` very easy.

```
library(dplyr);library(magrittr)

# if you know the columnames string pattern
  df2 %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = vars( reportID, dateSent, matches("otherVar") )) %>%
    summarize(Results = n() )

# or you prefer range of variables from:to 
  df2 %>%
    group_by_at(.vars = vars( reportID, dateSent, otherVar1:otherVar1)) %>%
    summarize(Results = n() )
```